# What is the Open Governance Model? How is it different from other models?

Tags: project-management, community

The prime example being [iojs](https://iojs.org/en/index.html) as a fork of [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/), where the main difference being (aside from the obvious advancement in technology versioning and being more up-to-date), is that iojs has an *Open Governance Model*, which nodejs does not.

What does that mean exactly? How are the two different?

Comment: Do you know if nodejs has a model of some sort?

Comment: If I'm interpreting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_governance) and [this article](http://sdtimes.com/node-js-announces-move-open-governance-model-establishes-node-js-foundation/) correctly, it just means that the community working on iojs can directly add feedback to govern the project's direction, which isn't the case with nodejs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that io.js forked from node.js in the first place was that those originally involved in the forked project wanted the community using the fork to be able to give feedback to the design and add improvements. In [the words of team member Mikeal Rogers](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2855057/application-development/why-iojs-decided-to-fork-nodejs.html),

> We've been working with Joyent since July to try and move the project to a structure where the contributors and community can step in and effectively solve the problems facing Node.
>
> . . .
>
> In my opinion, the best way to move Node forward is to get the community organized around solving problems and putting out releases, so that's what we're doing.

[Open-source governance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_governance) has been applied to a wide range of things, just as the open source movement has spread to many fields.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really tell what nodejs looks like (aside from being some javascript tool thingy), but the two projects appear to be very similar in nature.

According to iojs, it looks like Open Source Governance is a fancy way of calling something open source and indulges in its principles. I could be wrong in interpreting this, but here's what the project says:

> **What is open source governance?**
>
> Open source governance advocates the application of the philosophies of the open source and open content movements in order to enable any interested party to add to the creation of the end product, as with a wiki document. Legislation is democratically opened to the general citizenry, employing their collective wisdom to benefit the decision-making process and improve democracy.

Nodejs says that they have over 300 contributors, as well as some 15 people on a "technical steering committee."

Bottom line, open source governance is implementing the open source concept and placing it into action. Both sites seems to have this, except iojs seems to talk about it more...

Comment: Nice. That's a better definition than the one I gave.